# What is that super-secret mission the Odyssey is supposed to be on during Stargate Atlantis' Finale?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

> ["It's on some secret mission even I'm not supposed to know about."
>
>       —Steven Caldwell](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Odyssey#Secret_mission)

(during [Enemy at the Gate](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Enemy_at_the_Gate_%28episode%29))

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to the [Stargate Wiki](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Enemy_at_the_gate#Notes), this is a tie in to SGU:

> Joseph Mallozzi confirmed in his blog that the Odyssey's secret mission is Icarus Base related, thus informally introducing Stargate Universe.

Here's the direct answer from [said blog entry](http://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/may-12-2011-stargate-universe-beyond-season-2-what-might-have-been/):

> flo writes: “1/Was the odissey’s secret mission from EATG a plan for something ? stargate revolution?”
>
> Answer: Initially, Odyssey’s secret mission was tied to the search for a naquadria-rich planet capable of providing the energy needed to dial Destiny.

Comment: Looks like you (and Stargate Wiki) are right: http://josephmallozzi.wordpress.com/2011/05/12/may-12-2011-stargate-universe-beyond-season-2-what-might-have-been/

Comment: thanks #Andy and @Paperjam, I edited the relevant quote into the answer